# Java - MalformedURLException when inputting String from another class, but not when pasting that same String in

Tags: java, url

When instantiating a new URL, the first block of code below, from the class DrawImage works.
However, when I input the same String ("https://www.purchased.com/hubfs/template/favicon.png") from another class, RandomImage, the following error comes up:

I tried first with manually inputting the String.

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class DrawImage {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String link = "https://www.purchased.com/hubfs/template/favicon.png";
    System.setProperty("http.agent", "Chrome");
    URL url = new URL(link);
    Image image = ImageIO.read(url.openStream());

  }
}
```

**-> works as expected**

Then, I changed to providing a RandomImage (this is the one that yields the error message!)

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class DrawImage {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    RandomImage img = new RandomImage();
    String link = img.link;
    System.setProperty("http.agent", "Chrome");
    URL url = new URL(link);
    Image image = ImageIO.read(url.openStream());

  }
}
```

Following class provides the random image:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*

public class RandomImage {
  public static String link;

  public RandomImage() throws Exception {
    this.link = generateUsableImageLink();
  }
```

But when running this second approach, I am getting following error:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: "https://www.purchased.com/hubfs/template/favicon.png"
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at DrawImage.main(DrawImage.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:267).
```

I tried (as you see in code above) making RandomImage an object, but the error feed tells me the error is occurring when I create an instance of URL with input from RandomImage.

If I were to guess, the issue is caused by some interaction between imported packages or thrown errors in RandomImage. Character by character, the String I manually inputted and the String generated by RandomImage are identical. How would I go about addressing this?

Comment: My guess is that the `generateUsableImageLink` method (which you haven’t shown us) reads lines from a text file, and you created that text file in Notepad in Windows.  Notepad likes to save text files with a leading Byte Order Mark character, `\ufeff`, at the start.  This character is invisible, but you can check for it with `System.out.println(link.startsWith("\ufeff"));` (or, conversely, `System.out.println(link.startsWith("http"));`).

Comment: @VGR You are right about the text file! However, both of these print statements yield false. So there appears to be some blocking character, but not that one.

Comment: Oops, looks like Paul Mattson has it right.   generateUsableImageLink returns a string which starts and ends with double-quote characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `generateUsableImageLink` generates string with quotes.
Change this method so that it does not put quotes on the string.